# Display data from sqlite to simpledialog in flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, simpledialog

I want to display data from sqlite to SimpleDialog widget

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text('Select Category '),
        children: <Widget>[
          dbHelper.getCategories().then((val) {
            for (var item in val) {
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text('Food'),
              );
            }
          }),
      ],
    );
});
```

While doing this I am getting the below error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: this is my database query 

Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    //List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [ID, NOTE]);
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM categories");
    if (result.length == 0) return null;
    List<Category> list = result.map((row) {
      return Category.fromMap(row);
    }).toList();
    return list;
  }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add additional information to your question by editing it into the question, not as a comment.  It's also good to learn [how to format your question correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @sagarsalian Next time, please try to format your code. It's difficult to understand your code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `SimpleDialogOption` widgets to `children`, but you need to await for the future to complete before adding them.

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

This error should give you a hint: it expects widgets, and you are giving it a future (`dbHelper.getCategories().then((val)` returns a `Future`).

What works is awaiting for your categories before displaying the dialog. For this you can use a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: dbHelper.getCategories(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Select Category '),
            children: [
              for (var item in snapshot.data) {
                SimpleDialogOption(
                  onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
                  child: const Text('Food'),
                );
              }
            }
```